# Is it possible to list the Expected Result for a Shared Step in Microsoft Test Manager 2012?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I have Shared Step that contains about 7 steps. Is it possible to list an Expected Result for the entire Shared Step, instead of listing Expected Results for each of the individual steps that are contained within the Shared Step? See the screenshot for the field I'm trying to fill in... as much as I try to type there, Test Manager won't let me.

[image: Expected Result for Shared Steps]

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't put an expected result in that spot. Would putting the expected result in the last step of the shared steps work for you? Since the shared steps show all of the sub-steps during execution, the last step in the shared steps should have the final expected result.

In the past I've also just created a step after the shared step like "Verify Work Items and tasks were created successfully" and "All Work Items and tasks were created successfully" as the expected result.

Comment: Sadly, that won't do, since I have several test cases that use the same shared step, but each test case expects a different result at the end. Thus, I need to be able to change what is expected for each test.

Comment: The shared steps should be generic so that they can be used across many tests. Why wouldn't you want to create another step in line 2 that would have a specific step (even if it's an obvious step) and the results you would expect?

Comment: That's what I currently do. I was just wondering if there was a way to condense the steps, since the expected results would fit nicely to the right of the Shared Steps. (see photo for current method http://i.stack.imgur.com/fTDTH.png )